# Bitbucket: How can i create new branch without copying Master branch

Tags: github, bitbucket

I just need to create a new branch without copying the master branch which is already in repo.

Is there any way to create a separate branch which has separate code in the same repo?

Comment: You had selected the right answer before. If you create a branch from master (as the wrong answer suggests), it won't be a separate branch.

Answer (score 2):

[Since Git 2.23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), you would use the new (still experimental) command [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch).

In your case: [`git switch --orphan newBranch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt)

> Create a new orphan branch, named `<new-branch>`.
>   All tracked files are removed.

That branch won't have any common file/history with `master`.

(Before 2.23, [`git checkout --orphan <new-branch>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnewbranchgt), but using checkout is no longer recommended, since it deals both with files and branches)

Comment: I have not tried your solution because the issue is solved by answered provided by first answered. Thanks for your help.